# Pandas - groupby continuous datetime periods

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
    KEY   START       END         VALUE
0   A     2017-01-01  2017-01-16  2.1
1   B     2017-01-01  2017-01-23  4.3
2   B     2017-01-23  2017-02-10  1.7
3   A     2017-01-28  2017-02-02  4.2
4   A     2017-02-02  2017-03-01  0.8
```

I would like to `groupby` on `KEY` and `sum` on `VALUE` but only on continuous periods of time. For instance in the above example I would like to get:

```
   KEY  START       END         VALUE 
0  A    2017-01-01  2017-01-16  2.1
1  A    2017-01-28  2017-03-01  5.0
2  B    2017-01-01  2017-02-10  6.0
```

There are tow groups for `A` since there is a gap in the time periods. 
I would like to avoid for loops since the dataframe has tens of millions of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create helper `Series` by compare [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed `START` column per group and use it for `groupby`:

```
s = df.loc[df.groupby('KEY')['START'].shift(-1) == df['END'], 'END']
s = s.combine_first(df['START'])
print (s)
0   2017-01-01
1   2017-01-23
2   2017-01-23
3   2017-02-02
4   2017-02-02
Name: END, dtype: datetime64[ns]

df = df.groupby(['KEY', s], as_index=False).agg({'START':'first','END':'last','VALUE':'sum'})
print (df)
  KEY  VALUE      START        END
0   A    2.1 2017-01-01 2017-01-16
1   A    5.0 2017-01-28 2017-03-01
2   B    6.0 2017-01-01 2017-02-10
```

Comment: Thanks. However this only aggregates two rows at a time. Any idea how I could modify your solution if I have the same dataframe as describe in the original question plus an additional row with 'START' = 2017-03-01 and say '2017-03-31' for 'END'? In that situation there is a fully continuous period from 2017-01-28 to 2017-03-31 and the 3 rows should be aggregated together.

Comment: Not so easy, I try find solution, but if need it faster, can you create new question?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from jezrael works like a charm if there are only two consecutive rows to aggregate. In the new example, it would not aggregate the last three rows for `KEY = A`.

```
     KEY   START       END         VALUE
 0   A     2017-01-01  2017-01-16  2.1
 1   B     2017-01-01  2017-01-23  4.3
 2   B     2017-01-23  2017-02-10  1.7
 3   A     2017-01-28  2017-02-02  4.2
 4   A     2017-02-02  2017-03-01  0.8 
 5   A     2017-03-01  2017-03-23  1.0
```

The following solution (slight modification of jezrael's solution) enables to aggregate all rows that should be aggregated:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='START')
idx = df.groupby('KEY')['START'].shift(-1) != df['END']
df['DATE'] = df.loc[idx, 'START']
df['DATE'] = df.groupby('KEY').DATE.fillna(method='backfill')
df = (df.groupby(['KEY', 'DATE'], as_index=False)
        .agg({'START': 'first', 'END': 'last', 'VALUE': 'sum'})
        .drop(['DATE'], axis=1))
```

Which gives:

```
   KEY   START         END      VALUE
0   A  2017-01-01  2017-01-16    2.1
1   A  2017-01-28  2017-03-23    6.0
2   B  2017-01-01  2017-02-10    6.0
```

Thanks @jezrael for the elegant approach!