# Group Continuous range date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a pandas DataFrame that look like this :

```
   KEY      START        END
0    A 2021-01-01 2021-01-31
1    A 2021-01-15 2021-01-18
2    A 2021-01-03 2021-02-15
3    A 2021-03-01 2021-03-31
4    A 2021-04-01 2021-04-15
5    A 2021-04-16 2021-04-30
6    B 2021-01-02 2021-01-05
7    B 2021-01-01 2021-01-10
8    B 2021-01-15 2021-01-20
9    B 2021-01-19 2021-01-31
10   B 2021-03-01 2021-03-31
```

I would like group by KEY and continuous/included period.
For instance in the above example I would like to get:

```
  KEY      START        END
0   A 2021-01-01 2021-02-15
1   A 2021-03-01 2021-04-30
2   B 2021-01-01 2021-01-10
3   B 2021-01-15 2021-01-31
4   B 2021-03-01 2021-03-31
```

Regards

Comment: I have already check this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47485244/pandas-groupby-continuous-datetime-periods

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas to work with.  I don't have time to work it all out but thought I would share some ideas with you that might get you rolling.  (maybe later)

Select just the 'B' key for now: (Make sure START and END are datetime)

```
dfB = df[df['KEY']=='B'].copy()
```

Create a date range:

```
dfB['Range'] = dfB.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x['START'], end=x['END']), axis=1)
```

Create a DatetimeIndex with all the distinct dates:

```
dti = dfB['Range'].iloc[0].union_many(dfB['Range'][1:])
dti

DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04',
               '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06', '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08',
               '2021-01-09', '2021-01-10', '2021-01-15', '2021-01-16',
               '2021-01-17', '2021-01-18', '2021-01-19', '2021-01-20',
               '2021-01-21', '2021-01-22', '2021-01-23', '2021-01-24',
               '2021-01-25', '2021-01-26', '2021-01-27', '2021-01-28',
               '2021-01-29', '2021-01-30', '2021-01-31', '2021-03-01',
               '2021-03-02', '2021-03-03', '2021-03-04', '2021-03-05',
               '2021-03-06', '2021-03-07', '2021-03-08', '2021-03-09',
               '2021-03-10', '2021-03-11', '2021-03-12', '2021-03-13',
               '2021-03-14', '2021-03-15', '2021-03-16', '2021-03-17',
               '2021-03-18', '2021-03-19', '2021-03-20', '2021-03-21',
               '2021-03-22', '2021-03-23', '2021-03-24', '2021-03-25',
               '2021-03-26', '2021-03-27', '2021-03-28', '2021-03-29',
               '2021-03-30', '2021-03-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Now find consecutive day gaps greater than 1.  The result contains the starting days of ranges in the DatetimeIndex. The only start date missing is the first date in the series.

```
dti[pd.Series(dti).diff().dt.days>1]

DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-15', '2021-03-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

You would still have to work out how to turn this into a DF with start and end dates.  Also would have to do this as a result of a `groupby`.  Maybe in an `apply` function. (That's why I selected just KEY 'B' to start with)

I thought it would be better to give you half an answer than none at all.